# Why my radio button list fires only when the selected value = 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, radiobuttonlist

I don't know why my `radiobuttonlist` fires only when i select the second list item !

**My aspx :**

```
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_select_sign" runat="server" Visible="false">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rb_select_sign" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="rb_select_sign_SelectedIndexChanged" CausesValidation="false" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">normal</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">abnormal</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </asp:Panel> 
  <div class="events" dir="rtl">
        <fieldset>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_PageNew_UC" runat="server" Width="100%">
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_sign" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="false">
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rb_select_sign" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

---

**My .cs :**

```
 protected void rb_select_sign_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rb_select_sign.SelectedValue == "0")
            {
                pnl_PageNew_UC.Visible = true;
                pnl_sign.Visible = false;

            }
            else
            {
                pnl_PageNew_UC.Visible = false;
                pnl_sign.Visible = true;

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your problem starts not when the `selectedvalue =1`, it starts as soon as you set the visibility of the panels to true.

The problem itself is in your `AsyncPostBackTrigger`, your trigger is *outside* the UpdatePanel and therefore no longer triggered.

This can easily be solved, put the RadioButtonList inside the ContentTemplate:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_select_sign" runat="server" >
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rb_select_sign" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" ... />
    </asp:Panel> 
    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_PageNew_UC" runat="server" Width="100%">
    </asp:Panel>
....
```

Comment: sometime you can't put all controls in an update panel because of the page design.

Comment: @just_name I agree, it's annoying - but after a while you start getting the hand of it... :)

Comment: @namkha87 - You don't need all controls, you just need whatever you want to act as a postback trigger...

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnl_select_sign" runat="server">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rb_select_sign" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="rb_select_sign_SelectedIndexChanged" CausesValidation="false"
                    AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">normal</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">abnormal</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <div class="events" dir="rtl">
        <fieldset>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_PageNew_UC" runat="server" Width="100%">
                        123
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnl_sign" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="false">
                        312
                    </asp:Panel>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rb_select_sign" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

In Code behind:

```
        protected void rb_select_sign_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rb_select_sign.SelectedValue == "0")
            {
                pnl_PageNew_UC.Visible = true;
                pnl_sign.Visible = false;

            }
            else
            {
                pnl_PageNew_UC.Visible = false;
                pnl_sign.Visible = true;

            }

            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
```